# Sorting in linear time?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory, time-complexity

Given an input set of n integers in the range [0..n^3-1], provide a linear time sorting algorithm.

This is a review for my test on thursday, and I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Comment: Could you check the question again? N vs n? [0..n^31] vs [0..2^31] vs [0..2^32-1]?

Comment: @danbruc - Good point. Also, revision 1 says [0..n^3-1] - why is it [0..n^31] now?

Comment: I have no idea why this changed. I don't remember ever updating.

Comment: since the numbers are **equi-distant**, an [index-sort (custom sorting algorithm, using re-indexing)](http://foo123.github.io/examples/sorting-algorithms/#action=test&sorting_algorithm=IndexSort%20%28custom%29&data_size=20000&data_type=range&pre_sort_state=shuffled) can sort in strictly linear time and constant space (even if input includes duplicates)

Comment: You can also use sleep sort. For each number do `sleep(value); print (value)`. ;)

Comment: @KrzysztofHasiński this is funny :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Also take a look at related sorts too: [pigeonhole sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_sort) or [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort), as well as [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) as mentioned by Pukku.

Comment: Dont you think n^3-1 is a little too large to use counting sort? if n=100 you would have 100^3 space just to sort. He needs to change the base of the integers and use Radix sort.

Comment: With the range of n d-digit numbers being in [0, n^3 - 1], then the number of digit d is 3log(n) and the algorithm will run in O(dn) => O(nlog(n)). Radix sort is not a linear solution. Also, pigeonhole is not suitable either because the number of elements is not "approximately the same" of the number of possible keys..

Answer (score 24):

Have a look at [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).

Comment: Just a caveat, radix sort is only linear if you have a fixed max length for your keys...  since you have a range of integers, then yes, it can be linear, but this won't always be the case.

Comment: This is also known as "bucket sort".

Comment: With the range of n d-digit numbers being in [0, n^3 - 1], then the number of digit d is 3log(n) and the algorithm will run in O(dn) => O(nlog(n)). Radix sort is not a linear solution.

Comment: @GoatRider bucket sort is different from radix sort because it runs in linear time when the input is drawn from a uniform distribution while radix sort runs in linear time when the number of digits in the numbers (or keys in the elements) is constant...

Comment: @MarsellusWallace, could you expand on when radix sort is linear? Even with fixed number of digits, wouldn't it be O(n log n) time?

Answer (score 16):

When people say "sorting algorithm" they often are referring to "comparison sorting algorithm", which is any algorithm that only depends on being able to ask "is this thing bigger or smaller than that". So if you are limited to asking this one question about the data then you will never get more than n*log(n) (this is the result of doing a log(n) search of the n factorial possible orderings of a data set).

If you can escape the constraints of "comparison sort" and ask a more sophisticated question about a piece of data, for instance "what is the base 10 radix of this data" then you can come up with any number of linear time sorting algorithms, they just take more memory.

This is a time space trade off. Comparason sort takes little or no ram and runs in N*log(n) time. radix sort (for example) runs in O(n) time AND O(log(radix)) memory.

Comment: You can do an in place radix sort

Comment: @aaronman could you link to the linear time constant space sorting algorithm?

Comment: Sure, keep in mind when I say constant space it's in reference to the size of the range, the storage is not constant in regards to the size of what's being sorted (32bit v 64bit). here is a link ([radix](https://github.com/aaronjosephs/radix/blob/master/radix.cpp)) to my own implementation, the code is messy but it's the one named `msd16_radix`, it uses counting to do the sort in place, also it calls std::sort because it's faster for small arrays so my implementation isn't strictly inplace (if std::sort uses memory) but it is clear that it can be achieved inplace.

Comment: Now that I look at your answer again you do mention that the space is proportional to the radix. I guess you threw me off because you say it's a tradeoff, but if your radix is 16 or even 256 it's totally negligible to an array that could be millions or even a billion elements

Answer (score 3):

It's really simple, if n=2 and numbers are unique:

- Construct an array of bits (2^31-1 bits => ~256MB). Initialize them to zero.
- Read the input, for each value you see set the respective bit in the array to 1.
- Scan the array, for each bit set, output the respective value.

Complexity => O(2n)

Otherwise, use Radix Sort:

Complexity => O(kn) (hopefully)

Comment: The question says n^31 and not 2^31. Further you assume that no number appears more than once.

Comment: I'm assuming n=2. I think that's a typo. After all, we don't typically use other bases than 2.

You're right, I'm (probably incorrectly) assuming numbers are not repeated!

Comment: danbruc, I don't know your background, but my answer is very valid and well balanced (if I may say so).

Comment: initialization does take more than `O(n)` in this way...(Yet one would argue that OS could provide zeroed pages yeah...

Answer (score 3):

[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_algorithms#List_of_sorting_algorithms) shows quite many different sorting algorithms and their complexities. you might want to check them out

Answer (score 2):

A Set of a limited range of numbers can be represented by a bitmap of RANGE bits.
In this case, a 500mb bitmap, so for anything but huge lists, you'd be better off with Radix Sort.  As you encounter the number k, set bitmap[k] = 1. Single traversal through list, O(N).

Comment: Note that n might not equal 2.

Answer (score 2):

Think the numbers as three digit numbers where each digit ranges from 0 to n-1. Sort these numbers with radix sort. For each digit there is a call to counting sort which is taking Theta(n+n) time, so that the total running time corresponds to Theta(n).

Answer (score -2):

alike algo is possible:

```
M;// unsorted array
lngth; //number items of M
for(int i=0; i < lngth; i++)sorted[M[i]];
```

It's alone possible algo for linear complexity, but it has complexity O(k*N) by ram (N - number array elements, k -- element's len)