# Sorting a sequence in O(n) time

Tags: c#, java, c, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting in linear time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749585/sorting-in-linear-time)

Suppose we are given a sequence S of n elements, each of which is an integer in the range [0,n^2-1]. 
Can we sort it in O(n) time?

Please dont mind me asking too many interview questions. I am just appetent.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749585/sorting-in-linear-time

Comment: Did they ask all the questions from the book Programming Pearls?

Comment: are you sure the number of elements is meant to be the same as the number of bits in the largest integer?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If there are n^2-1 bits of memory available, simply scan the sequence, setting each bit indexed by a value of the sequence to 1. That is O(n) on the size of the sequence. Subsequently, testing for presence is then an O(1) operation.

Of course, if you want to read the sorted sequence out, it's O(n^2), because you need to sweep the entire collection of n^2-1 bits looking for the 1s.

Comment: >Of course, if you want to read the sorted sequence out.  Isn't this equivalent to say. If you know the algorithm for a problem thats O(1), but if you want to find the answer YMMV.

Comment: Actually producing the sorted sequence seems like a pretty large part of sorting a sequence. I could sort any sequence in zero time, if I am allowed to spend O(n^2) time to later read my sorted sequence out.

Comment: Could you explain a little more about this answer? I don't think it is clear on how this results in a sorted sequence of elements.

Comment: The introductory "if there are n^2-1 bits of memory available" is superflouos. The question is only referring to time constraints, hence there's an arbitrary amount of memory available. If you're a theoretical computer scientist, that is.

Comment: @Philip: Every memory bound is trivially also a time bound, as you can't read or write N memory in less than O(N) time.

Comment: @Paŭlo: Right, but I can write a *fixed* amount of memory in a *constant* amount of time, independent of N. For instance, if I change mergesort to first compute the first 1.000.000 primes and then proceed with mergesort as expected, this doesn't change mergesort's asymptotic runtime of O(n*log n). If there's no memory constraint, memory is infinite.

Answer (score 10):

No.

When the only precondition is an integer in the range 0-N².

- Counting sorts won't work because the scanning, be it bit-patterns for distinct inputs or buckets for duplicate inputs, would complete in O(N²)
- The range would make the key length for radix sort dependent on N hence radix won't work in O(N).

Any statement involving "When N is small" invalidates any O based argument.

Answer (score 4):

Just use [Radix Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).

Comment: Radix under these conditions would make the k in Radix O(kN) dependent on N. Not good, and not an answer to OP.

Answer (score 3):

There are O(N) (as opposed to NlogN) sorting algorithms for some special cases where you've got a known, bounded set of objects (e.g. integers in a specified range) :

[radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)

[bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort)

Comment: Yes, but this range has to be also in O(N), which it is not here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if we have a hash-like function that for any integer computes its position in the sorted array in O(1) time. However designing such hash-function is IMO problematic - I can't come up with any detailed ideas of how it could work.

Comment: How can your hash function decide the position of the value 1 (say) without knowing whether 0 is in S?

Comment: @dfan: No idea, that's just a "here's what we need for that" answer.

Comment: It seems impossible to me, since the position of an integer in the sorted array depends on the values of the other elements in S.

Answer (score 0):

[Programming Pearls](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201657880) covers variations on this problem. If S is large and you can assume that there are no duplicates, the fastest approach is to allocate a bit vector of length n^2, and use it to mark the presence or absence of each number in the range.

Comment: "allocate a bit vector of length n^2" renders the answer to OP a clear no.

Answer (score 0):

If `n` is small enough, you can use histogram. Build histogram from input sequence, then construct the output sequence from that histogram. Pseudocode:

```
H = histogram(input_sequence);
while (not H.empty):
    E = H.smallest_value_element()
    //E.value - value of element, E.count - count in input sequence
    H.remove(E)
    repeat E.count times: output_sequence.append(E.value)
```