# Double dimension array sorting in O(n) time

Tags: c, arrays, complexity-theory, array-algorithms

I was asked a question in interview for sorting a double dimension array in O(n) time.How is it possible to do it in O(n).Can someone shed some light on it.. Thank you.

Input:

```
3 5 7 1
4 9 2 0
9 3 6 2
```

Output

```
0 1 2 2 
3 3 4 5  
6 7 9 9
```

Comment: You need to tell us what sorting a two-dimensional array means before we can answer this question.

Comment: What exactly is a double dimension array? A 2D one? If so, what is the size of that array (`n` x `n`?)

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749585/sorting-in-linear-time

Comment: Given your example, I see no difference between that array and a single dimension representation of 12 elements that would have any effect on sorting complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can sort as a plain array.**
E.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    return *(int*)a - *(int*)b;
}

#define ROW_SIZE 3
#define COL_SIZE 4

int main(void){
    int M[ROW_SIZE][COL_SIZE]={{3,5,7,1},{4,9,2,0},{9,3,6,2}};
    int c,r,*p;

    for(p=&M[0][0],r=0;r<ROW_SIZE;++r){
        for(c=0;c<COL_SIZE;++c){
            printf("%d ",*p++);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    qsort(&M[0][0], ROW_SIZE*COL_SIZE, sizeof(int), cmp);
    for(p=&M[0][0],r=0;r<ROW_SIZE;++r){
        for(c=0;c<COL_SIZE;++c){
            printf("%d ",*p++);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what did you actually mean by double dimension array, but there are sorting algorithms specific for some situations that can achieve O(n). An example of that is [Counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort), if you want to sort an array with 1000 integers in the range 1 to 1000, it can sort in O(n).

**EDIT:** The fact that it's a multidimensional array does not change logic of the sorting. You can convert the index (using by the sorting) to the bidimensional index like this:

```
array[i / N][i % N];
```

Where N is the size of the first dimension.

Comment: +1 For correct answer. However you'd be better wait what the OP actually means before answering...:)