# Find the rank of each element of double[] array in better way in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, rank

I have written code to calculate the rank of each element of a double[] array in the following code. For an example, if I have `double` array `{3, 1.3, 2, 3}` then I find the rank as `{2, 0, 1, 2}`. It has been calculated as

- 1.3 is least so it got rank 0.
- 2 is the next, so it got rank 1.
- 3 is the next bigger number, so both 3's get rank 2.

```java
public static void main() {
    double[] x = {3, 1.3, 2, 3};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x) + " - original");
    System.out.println("[2, 0, 1, 2] - should be");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(findRank(x)) + " - our rank");
}

private static int[] findRank(double[] x){
    List<Double> lst = new ArrayList<Double>();
    int[] rank=new int[x.length]; // maximum length for already unique array
    for(double d:x)
        if (lst.indexOf(d) == -1) //only unique elements in list
            lst.add(d);

    Collections.sort(lst);
    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
        rank[i]=lst.indexOf(x[i]);
    }
    return rank;
}
```

This code gives the following output

```
[3.0, 1.3, 2.0, 3.0] - original
[2, 0, 1, 2] - should be
[2, 0, 1, 2] - our rank
```

What I am interested in is the better implementation of above code. How can it be done in a better way?

Edit

This question asks for duplicate elements to be ranked similarly and continuously i.e. `{0,1,2,3,...}` without skipping the intermediate rank, which is different from similar but different question
[How to find what is the rank of each element in an integer array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31918544/how-to-find-what-is-the-rank-of-each-element-in-an-integer-array). That question requires output `{3,0,1,3}` if the input `{3,1,2,3}` is given. i.e. it handles duplicate elements differently, or it breaks on duplicate values in input. But this is about handling duplicates too and the desired output is `{2,0,1,2}`.

Comment: why did you delete the code from the question?

Comment: How can it be done? Can you explain in detail?

Comment: @progy_rock, it was a typo while editing the formatting of question. It has been corrected.

Comment: Are you looking for code simplicity or efficiency?

Comment: I am primarily looking for efficiency. Code simplicity can be another desirable quality.

Comment: Vote for reopen as this question involved possible duplicate values in input array @Prabhu recommend editing if you want it reopened. FYI you can use a TreeSet together with a Map (for indeces - multiple indexOf calls is pretty inneficient).

Answer (score 1):

I would go for this approach:

```
public static int[] findRank(double[] inp) {
    int[] outp = new int[inp.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
        for(int k = 0; k < inp.length; k++) {
            if(inp[k] < inp[i]) outp[i]++;
        }
    }
    return outp;
}
```

I just came up with this on the fly, so I can't tell 100% if it is realy faster than your way, but I would say it looks nicer and you don't need to depend one the java implementations of `Collections.sort()` and Lists in general.

Comment: This is O(n^2), definitely not faster than the original way of doing this.

Comment: It is faster on arrays with a size of less than ~7000

Comment: This solution works, but seems to be more time complex than my solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for efficiency, don't go for finding the index of list with `list.indexOf()` multiple times. The time complexity of finding element in a list is O(n) as explained by http://infotechgems.blogspot.com/2011/11/java-collections-performance-time.html

You can use `Map` instead of `List`. Finding the element by key in `Map` uses O(1) complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming sort is O(n log(n)), then a single O(n) pass will generate unique rank. Sort array of Integers I[] according to x[] using lambda compare (lambda compare requires I[] to be of type Integer). Then generate unique rank R[] according to I[] and x[].

```
// return unique rank
private static int[] findRank(double[] x){
    int [] R = new int[x.length];
    if(x.length == 0)return R;
    Integer [] I = new Integer[x.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        I[i] = i;
    Arrays.sort(I, (i0, i1) -> (int) Math.signum(x[i0]-x[i1]));
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        if(x[I[i]] != x[I[j]])
            j = i;
        R[I[i]] = j;
    }
    return R;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues with efficiency in your code. The first and foremost one is the use of `array.indexOf()`. Finding index in array is costly O(n). You can instead create a `Map` in place of array, and use `x.get(key)` to get the rank associated with that. You can define and get keys in map as:

```
Map<Double,Integer> x = new HashMap<Double, Integer>();
x.put(3.5,0);
x.put(2.0,1);
x.put(4.1,2);
//.... and put following in loop
y=x.get(2.0); //y=1
```

But using Double as `key` in `HashMap` can be done, but it might not be very good idea as `Double` comparison might have floating point issues. But the basic idea is to use O(1) cost.