# Sorting integers in given interval

Tags: algorithm

I have `n` integers in the interval `[0,n^c]` where `c` is some positive integer.

Which algorithm can I use to sort those integers in linear time?

I did look at RadixSort by my problem is the following: Given the interval the longest digit has at most c*nlogn digits, so wouldnt RadixSort run in O(n*logn) time ?

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is a *radix sort*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting in linear time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749585/sorting-in-linear-time)

Comment: @Coldspeed: I did have a look at radix Sort. But if I understand radix sort correctly I need m "Buckets" where m is the number of digits of the longest integer. Given my interval the "longest " digit has at most c*logn digits (base 10)

Comment: Wouldn`t the runtime of radixSort be O(nlogn) instead of O(n) since the digits have length c*nlogn  ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use radix sort. You might say that it is not efficient enough, because the number of digits is log(n^c) so total time complexity is O(nlogn). However, you don't have to sort in base 10! you can probably convert your numbers to base n in constant time (depends on n), and radix  sort in base n, since log_n(n^c) = c.

Comment: I think you are right. To convert one of those integers into base n I need at most c operations. So I can convert all of my n integers in c*n=O(n) (linear time). Additionally, the length of the digits is always bounded by c.