# Time Complexity of Java PriorityQueue (heap) insertion of n elements?

Tags: java, time-complexity, heap, priority-queue

I would like to know what the time complexity of Java `PriorityQueue.Add()` is for `n` elements.

I understand that potential worse case insertion a single element is `O(log(n))`, but it is not clear to me what the time complexity is for inserting a collection of `n` elements?

I've seen claims from various sources (with no proofs) that the time to build a priority queue heap of `n` elements it is `O(n)`, and have also seen claims that it is `O(nlog(n))`, which makes sense given insertion is `O(log(n))`, which multiplied `n` times would indeed equal `O(nlog(n))`

Note: I'm only interested in worse case, not amortized.

This question assumes there is a logical way to describe the act of populating a data structure (heap) with `n` elements, that is different than simply considering `n` x `log(n)` insertions individually.

I'm making no assumptions regarding the input (such as a bounds on the set of input values, or a partially ordered input).

Comment: the guy below is playing on your wrong definition. with the time complexity of inserting into data structures usually means that if you have n elements in the structure, what is the time complexity of inserting 1 element into it. you said inserting n elements. you can't insert less than n if you want to insert n.

Comment: @MarianP Is there no standard logical way to describe the act of "populating" a data structure with `n` elements? It is a fairly common scenario.

Comment: @pjs yes you are right, that is a duplicate. I will add my vote to close and point to existing question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is *O(N log N)* in the general case. An *O(N)* algorithm exists for the special case where the input is already ordered, but this isn't provided in `java.util.PriorityQueue`.

Comment: Interestingly there are more elaborate methods to sort in linear time assuming the input is of a specific type, some are mentioned in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749585/sorting-in-linear-time

Comment: @gue Oh yeah. For example if the input is already in the correct PQ order it is just `pq.a[i++] = input.nextElement()`.

Comment: Pre-sorted data is not required, there's a Theta(n) algorithm that works with any set of data.  See the linked answer.

Comment: How about: log 1, log 2... log N for inserting 1st, 2nd, .... Nth element? log 1 + log 2 + ... + log N = log N!

Comment: @VyshnavRameshThrissur That's not how Big-O notation works.

Answer (score 25):

It seems like the insertion of n elements should be O(n log n)

**Java PriorityQueue** ([Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html))

> O(log n) time for the enqueing and dequeing methods (offer, poll, 
>   remove() and add)
>
> O(n) for the remove(Object) and contains(Object) methods
>
> O(1) for the retrieval methods (peek, element, and size)

These time complexities seem all worst case ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue)), except for `.add()`. You are right to question the bounds as the Java Doc also states to the extension of this unbound structure:

> The details of the growth policy are not specified

As they state in the Doc as well, the PriorityQueue is based on an array with a specific initial capacity. I would assume that the growth will cost O(n) time, which then would also be the worst case time complexity for `.add()`.

To get a guaranteed O(n log n) time for adding n elements you may state the size of your n elements to omit extension of the container:

```
PriorityQueue(int initialCapacity)
```

---

**EDIT:**
To the claim of O(n) time for construction is correct (as stated by @pjs in the comments). This procedure is often called [heapify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap) and works on an pre existing array that is used to construct a binary tree on it in O(n) time.

Comment: Sorry, but your intuition (and therefore your answer) is wrong about building a heap.  I've flagged this as a duplicate, you can find the correct answer along with multiple links to sources and proofs there.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I modified that part of my answer. I do not find this as a duplicate as the question is related to the .add() method of a specific Java container and not about the construction of a general heap.