# What is the time complexity of this priorityQueue

Tags: java, algorithm

I have the below code, I wanted to know what is the time complexity of this code when I am using PriorityQueue.

I have a listOfNumbers of size N

```
Queue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<>();
q.addAll(listOfNumbers);

while(q.size()>1) {
    q.add(q.poll()+q.poll()); // add sum of 2 least elements back to Queue
}
```

As per this post : [Time Complexity of Java PriorityQueue (heap) insertion of n elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47420638/time-complexity-of-java-priorityqueue-heap-insertion-of-n-elements)

O(log n) time for the enqueing and dequeing methods (offer, poll, remove() and add)

Now how to calculate the time when I am adding the element back to Queue again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The running time of your program is log(n) + log(n-1) + ... + log(1).

This is log(n!) (by repeated application of the log rule log(a) + log(b) = log(ab)).

log(n!) is Theta(n log n) see [Is log(n!) = Θ(n·log(n))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095395/is-logn-%CE%98n-logn)

So your program runs in Theta(n log n) time.

Answer (score 1):

On `q.add(q.poll()+q.poll());` the number of element in queue is always O(N). So, the enqueue still works in O(log(N)).

Comment: So time complexity of my program is N*Log(N) or just Log(N)?